# How to get nested values from json in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json file i wanted to use as a database simply because I like the structure of json than mysql php i have the following code

```
$query = "people.json";
$json = file_get_contents($query);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$faq = $data['FAQ'];
$questions = $faq['Questions']['Number'];
foreach($questions as $question){
    $number = $question['number'];
    $question = $question['question'];
    $answer = $question['answer'];
?>

{
    "FAQ":{
        "Questions":{
            "Number":{
                "1":{
                    "number":"one",
                    "question":"How do i trade with Marketwh steam bots?",
                    "answer":"You can Trade one of 2 ways <br> Send a Trade offer to one of our Steam Bots <br> & #8226; find the item on our site see the price of it and then click trade and send a trade offer like normal."
                },
                "2":{
                    "number":"two",
                    "question":"What is a Steam Bot?",
                    "answer":"A Steam Bot is an automated Trading Bot that will automatcally accept offers sent to it that are within the item price range of buying or selling."
                },
                "3":{
                    "number":"three",
                    "question":"What is a Steam Bot?",
                    "answer":"A Steam Bot is an automated Trading Bot that will automatcally accept offers sent to it that are within the item price range of buying or selling."
                },
                "4":{
                    "number":"four",
                    "question":"",
                    "answer":""
                },
                "5":{
                    "number":"five",
                    "question":"",
                    "answer":""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

$number outputs "one"
$question outputs the question
$answer outputs the first letter in the question variable for the first one it is "H" and the second and third answer it is a "W". 
as you can see in the code above i have it in a foreach which should cycle through each of the numbers 1-4 in the FAQ array
I am using this to call in php for the database i can just edit and change the stuff with my website and FAQ is the FAQ page i will be using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had in the Original question

```
$query = "people.json";
$json = file_get_contents($query);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$faq = $data['FAQ'];
$questions = $faq['Questions']['Number'];
foreach($questions as $question){
    $number = $question['number'];
    $question = $question['question'];
    $answer = $question['answer'];
?>
```

I changed the code in the php like this

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$questions = $data['FAQ']['Questions']['Number'];
foreach($questions as $quest){
    $number = $quest['number'];
    $question = $quest['question'];
    $answer = $quest['answer'];
?>
```

i had called the $question in the foreach and once after that i changed the $question in the foreach to $quest and it fixed it, once i realized that it was probably conflicting like that and the json to the original way i asked about and i did try the [{}] way to do it as an array but it needed an object and the out put is just like how i wanted thanks for the answers and i am glad i figured out what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

$questions is an object, not a list.  I expect you need to change your json format so the questions are in a list.  Like the following:

```
{
  "FAQ": {
    "Questions": {
      "Number": [
        {
          "number": "one",
          "question": "How do i trade with Marketwh steam bots?",
          "answer": "You can Trade one of 2 ways <br> Send a Trade offer to one of our Steam Bots <br> & #8226; find the item on our site see the price of it and then click trade and send a trade offer like normal."
        },
        {
          "number": "two",
          "question": "What is a Steam Bot?",
          "answer": "A Steam Bot is an automated Trading Bot that will automatcally accept offers sent to it that are within the item price range of buying or selling."
        },
        {
          "number": "three",
          "question": "What is a Steam Bot?",
          "answer": "A Steam Bot is an automated Trading Bot that will automatcally accept offers sent to it that are within the item price range of buying or selling."
        },
        {
          "number": "four",
          "question": "",
          "answer": ""
        },
        {
          "number": "five",
          "question": "",
          "answer": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok i understand about the [{}] thing but when i call the values it says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Nevermind it did work as i wanted in the firstplace that way Did not work it was

Answer (score 0):

As **user3720435** said, update your JSON to make `Number` an `array ([])` instead of an `Object ({})`. You are not able to iterate over objects like you're wanting, however, this can be achieved with an array. Please see the following for information regarding your specific question.

https://so.amarokstudios.com/NestedJSONValues/